# APL and Java Interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, apl

Are you aware of a good way to connect a java based webapp with an APL implementation? I read about a wrapper component that can do it, by exposing implementations as web services. Besides that - is there anything else out there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for delay in answering but I've not notification of your post from StackOverflow.

Dyalog APL has not a tight integration with Java as IBM APL2.
Unfortunately the Java APL2 inteface is not portable to Dyalog APL that has, instead, a strong integration in the Microsoft .NET architecture.

Maybe you should make a wrapper to pass data to/from a java piece of code but, in my experience, I would not recommend this approach especially if you are developing software for a client.

Finally could be that using Microsoft Java programming languages (Visual J# or J++) you can found some "bridge" among .NET and JVM architectures (e.g. parameters passing).

Answer (score 0):

Regard APL it's necessary to address the right product, like IBM APL2, Dyalog APL and so on.

I can answer that Yes, it is possible with IBM APL2. The Java-APL2 interface is well documented in the APL2 User's Guide (http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/c187021i.pdf) You can directly go to page (pdf) 582.

Comment: Mario, Thanks for the response. The APL version that I need is Dyalog APL. Also, the java interface classes that you mentioned below - are they scalable?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another insight, APL2 make available four Java interface classes:

**Apl2interp** Make APL2 interpreter requests (to give commands to APL2)

**Apl2object** Manage APL2 workspace objects (to move arrays from Java to APL2 and vice-versa)

**Apl2exception** Indicate and detect APL2 errors

**Apl2cdr** Convert between workspace and CDR formats

Answer (score 0):

java environment includes a number of development tools,classes and methods. the development kit are the part of system known as Java Development kit(JDK)and the class and methods are part of the java Standard Library(JCL),also known as the Application Progaramming Interface

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.